# How to pass variables to custom function in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

there,
In my bash script, I define a command line function:

```
rep() {
 find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/$1/$2/g' {} \;
}
```

After source ~/.bashrc
when I type: `rep get foo`
It doesn't work. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is very unspecific.  Until I read the answer I thought your code failed to define the function somehow. My bad for being on the wrong track, but as the instructions in the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) amplify many times over, you want to be as specific as possible next time.

Answer (score 4):

Single quotes around the sed `'s/$1/$2/g'` prevent bash from evaluating the `$1` and `$2` function arguments into strings - your command right now will swap a file with `$1` in it for `$2`.

Try using double quotes instead.

```
rep() {
 find . -type f -exec sed -i -e "s/$1/$2/g" {} \;
}
```

Comment: Actually, the OP's attempt would not swap literal `$1` because `$` in a regex represents the end of line. There can obviously not be anything after end of line, so `$1` would never match anything; and so the OP's script would do nothing at all (except needlessly  copy the file over itself).